# Error with two video NetStreams AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, video, netstream

I have 2 NetStream objects that I am trying to assign 2 videos to (one to each), and then, because I have 2 native windows, I use `stage.addChild(video);` and `secondWindow.stage.addChild(video2);`. I am using `stream.play("scene1.f4v");` and `stream2.play("scene1A.f4v");` to specify the files for the streams. I am now diagnosing an error, because the videos are not playing. Instead, I get the following error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Function/detectText()[/Users/Jared/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/InTheAirNet_MultiviewPlayer/src/InTheAirNet_MultiviewPlayer.as:124]

Line 124 is `secondWindow.stage.addChild(video2);`. Is this error due to an issue with my file URLS? I have the video files in a folder named `assets` in the structure for my application.

I think that is enough, but I will include my code too- just in case:

```
package
{

import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.display.NativeWindow;
import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
import flash.display.NativeWindowSystemChrome;
import flash.display.Screen;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;


public class InTheAirNet_MultiviewPlayer extends Sprite {

    public var secondWindow:NativeWindow;
    public static var nativeApplication:Object;
    private var connection:NetConnection;
    private var stream:NetStream;
    private var stream2:NetStream;
    private var video:Video;
    private var video2:Video;

    public function InTheAirNet_MultiviewPlayer() {

        // Ouput screen sizes and positions (for debugging)
        for each (var s:Screen in Screen.screens) trace(s.bounds);                

        // Make primary (default) window's stage go fullscreen
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
        stage.color = 0xC02A2A; // red


        // Create fullscreen window on second monitor (check if available first)
        if (Screen.screens[1]) {

            // Second window
            var nwio:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
            nwio.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE;
            secondWindow = new NativeWindow(nwio);
            secondWindow.bounds = (Screen.screens[1] as Screen).bounds;
            secondWindow.activate();

            // Second window's stage
            secondWindow.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            secondWindow.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            secondWindow.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
            secondWindow.stage.color = 0x387D19; // green   
        }

        //Create array of scenes and their overlays
        var videos:Array = [
            {
                primary:'scene1.f4v',
                secondary:['scene1A.f4v','scene1B.f4v']
            },
            {
                primary:'scene2.f4v',
                secondary:['scene2A.f4v','scene2B.f4v']
            },
            {
                primary:'scene3.f4v',
                secondary:['scene3A.f4v','scene3B.f4v']
            },
            {
                primary:'scene4.f4v',
                secondary:['scene4A.f4v','scene4B.f4v']
            },
            {
                primary:'scene5.f4v',
                secondary:['scene5A.f4v','scene5B.f4v']
            }
        ]

        //Keyboard event listener and key assignment
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, detectText);

        function detectText(keyboardevent:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (keyboardevent.keyCode == 38) { //UP
                //Previous scene
            }
            if (keyboardevent.keyCode == 40) { //DOWN
                //Next scene
            }
            if (keyboardevent.keyCode == 37) { //LEFT
                //Previous overlay
            }
            if (keyboardevent.keyCode == 39) { //RIGHT
                //Next overlay
            }
            if (keyboardevent.keyCode == 27) { //ESCAPE
                //Terminate application
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(); 
            }

            //START static video objects for BETA
            //Create the NetConnection
            connection = new NetConnection();

            //Set NetConnection to streaming mode; null specifies NO media server connection
            connection.connect(null);

            //Create the NetStream
            stream = new NetStream(connection);
            stream2 = new NetStream (connection);

            //Set NetStream client to recieve certain events
            stream.client = this;
            stream2.client = this;

            //Create video objects
            var video:Video = new Video();
            var video2:Video = new Video();

            //Add video objects to their stages
            stage.addChild(video);
            secondWindow.stage.addChild(video2);

            //Attach the NetStream to the video object
            video.attachNetStream(stream);
            video2.attachNetStream(stream2);

            //Set the default buffer time to 1 second
            stream.bufferTime = 1;
            stream2.bufferTime = 1;

            //Tell the stream to recieve the video
            stream.receiveVideo(true);
            stream2.receiveVideo(true);

            //Play a F4V file
            stream.play("scene1.f4v");
            stream2.play("scene1A.f4v");
        }

    }

        }
}
```

Comment: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." means that what you're trying to refer to doesn't actually exist, so I'd start by putting trace() in few places to check out what doesn't exist and why
// edit
or just put a break point somewhere before line 124

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what is wrong. I have the application create a second native window if it detects the presence of a second monitor. However, in my code to create my NetConnection, stream, and video head, I don't use an IF statement at all. So while I am trying to run the application without the second monitor, there is no secondary native window to run the video head on- hence the error.

Now I am going to have to figure out why the video for the first native window isn't playing.